# Does the order of the fields matter when setting up the schema.xml?

Tags: solr, solr4

From what I have found so far only the order of the filters matter.

But, does the order in which the <field ...> are added matter?

I'd prefer to alphabetize and group by multiValued but not clear if the order has any significance to Solr.

This is against Solr 4.x currently but I will also be working on Solr 8.x stuff here soon enough.

So, does the order matter on any of the Solr versions?

Comment: No, the order in the schema does not matter. The order of multiple values added to a multi-valued field will be retained.